# specifying anything but a row and a column combination in an r matrix

Tags: r

I have a vector of row/column names in a a square matrix of coefficients.
That is the row and columns are identical:

```
CoeffcientNames<-c(n1,n2,n3,n4)
```

The matrix looks like this:

```
   n1  n2  n3  n4 
n1 1   0.2 0.3 0.4 
n2 0.1  1  0.2 0.3
n3 0.1 0.2  1  0.4
n4 0.1 0.2 0.3  1
```

My intention is to choose each of these Coefficient Names at a time
by their vector index number: `CoefficientNames[i]`

Then I want to leave the Coefficient's row and column as is, and turn the rest of the matrix to zeros.

If we are using `n2` (`CoefficientNames[2]`) this will look like this:

```
>CoefficientMatrix
   n1  n2  n3  n4 
n1 0   0.2  0   0 
n2 0.1  1  0.2 0.3
n3 0   0.2  0   0
n4 0   0.2  0   0
```

The logic of course is any cell that is does not have 2 in it's x or it's y index becomes zero. But I will need to use the names as indexes.

I tried things like:

```
CoefficientMatrix[CoefficientNames[!i],CoefficientNames[!i]]=0
```

, or

```
CoefficientMatrix[!CoefficientNames[i],!CoefficientNames[i]]=0
```

, or

```
CoefficientMatrix[dimnames(CoefficientMatrix) != paste(CoefficientNames[i]),dimnames(CoefficientMatrix) != paste(CoefficientNames[i]] = 0
```

This can be looped of course, but I'm rather new to r and I'm sure there is an elegant way to accomplish this with the right use of writing conventions. Any help will be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We can create a function with `row/col`

```
f1 <- function(mat, ind) {
      mat * (!(row(mat) != ind  & col(mat) != ind))

  }
f1(m1, 2)
#   n1  n2  n3  n4
#n1 0.0 0.2 0.0 0.0
#n2 0.1 1.0 0.2 0.3
#n3 0.0 0.2 0.0 0.0
#n4 0.0 0.2 0.0 0.0



f1(m1, 1)
#    n1  n2  n3  n4
#n1 1.0 0.2 0.3 0.4
#n2 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.0
#n3 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.0
#n4 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.0

f1(m1, 3)
#    n1  n2  n3  n4
#n1 0.0 0.0 0.3 0.0
#n2 0.0 0.0 0.2 0.0
#n3 0.1 0.2 1.0 0.4
#n4 0.0 0.0 0.3 0.0
```

---

And it can be done in a loop all at once

```
lapply(seq_len(nrow(m1)), f1, mat = m1)
```

#### data

```
m1 <- structure(c(1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 1, 
0.3, 0.4, 0.3, 0.4, 1), .Dim = c(4L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(c("n1", 
"n2", "n3", "n4"), c("n1", "n2", "n3", "n4")))
```

Comment: First, thank you so much for this. As I said in my other comment: I need to get the row/column list out of a list of names. Therefore indexes will not work unless they are from a vector of names. Taking the whole matrix will not do it as well, since I only use some of the columns, and some of those repetitively. Apologies if this was not clear in my original question. And another question  - how are the cells zeroed when you are not stating a zero value?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way with `lapply` from base R (used simple to create dummy data). Since rows and columns are identical, simply using indexes should work fine. -

```
CoefficientNames <- c("n1", "n3", "n4")

lapply(which(colnames(m) %in% CoefficientNames), function(x) {
  m[-x, -x] <- 0
  m
})

[[1]]
   n1 n2 n3 n4
n1  1  5  9 13
n2  2  0  0  0
n3  3  0  0  0
n4  4  0  0  0

[[2]]
   n1 n2 n3 n4
n1  0  0  9  0
n2  0  0 10  0
n3  3  7 11 15
n4  0  0 12  0

[[3]]
   n1 n2 n3 n4
n1  0  0  0 13
n2  0  0  0 14
n3  0  0  0 15
n4  4  8 12 16
```

Data -

```
m <- matrix(1:16, nrow = 4, dimnames = list(paste0("n", 1:4), paste0("n", 1:4)))

   n1 n2 n3 n4
n1  1  5  9 13
n2  2  6 10 14
n3  3  7 11 15
n4  4  8 12 16
```

Comment: First, thank you for this: I may not have been clear enough when defining the problem: I need to get the row/column list out of a list of names. Therefore indexes will not work unless they are from a vector of names. Taking the whole matrix will not do it as well, since I only use some of the columns, and some of them repetitively. Apologies for not making this clear on my original question.

Comment: @Saar See if my updated answer helps otherwise consider adding more clarity to your question.

Comment: Hi, thank you Shree for replying and updating you answer. I have actually came up with an elegant solution and will post it in detail later in the day, if stack overflow lets me (I'm not sure what's the policy for newbies). If they wont let me post an answer, I will post this to you personally. If which is similar to grep in the sense that it output column numbers, my solution is very similar to yours.

Comment: @Saar anyone can post answers so you should be fine. Also, grep and which are likely to be the same in this case.

Answer (score 0):

As I said I actually found a way to do this using an index number to get a name from a column name vector, and then using grep get an index number of the Data matrix line/column and negate it.

Because I have to use one index number for this and about 7-8 other actions that have to be preformed simultaneously each instance, my solution cannot be lapply based, but has to be a part of a for loop and generate one matrix at a time. It does save using a dedicated loop within such a loop and therefore, I think, worth sharing:

```
Data
    n1  n2  n3  n4 
n1 1   0.2 0.3 0.4
n2 0.1  1  0.2 0.3
n3 0.1 0.2  1  0.4
n4 0.1 0.2 0.3  1 

Vector of column names
    CoefficientNames<-c("n1","n2","n3","n4")

Data[-grep(paste(CoefficientNames[i]),rownames(Data))
           ,-grep(paste(CoefficientNames[i]),colnames(Data))]=0
```

Comment: This exactly the same approach as my answer. Btw, you don't need to use `paste` function here. You can just do `-grep(CoefficientNames[i], rownames(Data))`.

Comment: Actually I do, tried it without paste before sharing this, it did not work. but I accept that this may sometimes be the case, if it worked with your data.